# Загрузить/обновить файлы в репозиторий GITLAB, лучший путь?

Tags: python, api, fileupload, gitlab, git-commit

*Всем доброго времени суток, я начинающий веб-разработчик, так что тапками прошу не кидаться :) Хочу отметить, что задача решается на стеке python&&django, но если вы имели опыт решения аналогичной задачи на другом стеке(, ЯП) мне он также очень интересен.*

К сути дела, стоит следующая задача:

Необходимо реализовать сервис(приложение/веб-интерфейс), который поможет делать коммиты, с соответствующими файлами.
Я получаю доступ к аккаунту user-a через API, посредством access_token-а, сообщение коммита, ветку и **архив с файлами и !директориями**(через уже разработанный мной интерфейс).

Далее распаковываю архив во временную директорию и вот тут встаёт вопрос каким образом лучше решить **задачу отправки файлов и commit-a.**

На данный момент, исходя из документации по API я вижу только 2 пути:

1. Клонировать репозиторий, который может быть достаточно больших
   размеров, на что может уйти неизвестное время, и затем производить все дальнейшие манипуляции уже непосредственно через git. **Тут есть 3 нюанса(я уверен, что даже больше): длительность всего процесса, проблемы с обработкой ошибок и самый главный это авторизация, так как в моем приложении пароль и логин от аккаунта пользователя на gitlab не хранится и храниться не будет, и пользователь авторизован в моём приложении пока не удалит условный sessionId из cookie.**
2. Строить n-ый список запросов, или использовать пакет python-gitlab(что несильно упрощает задачу), и encode-ть каждый файл перед отправкой в base64, **на что тоже может уйти неопределенное время. Стоит отметить что файлы могут самых разных типов psd, exe, txt, py, js и т.д.**
3. Может вы что-то предложите ? :)

**Так вот какой путь лучше и почему ?**

Comment: если хотите отслеживать большие бинарные файлы, то не следует их в сам git репозиторий добавлять напрямую. Вероятно вы хотите что-то вроде `git lfs`. Если вам с историей не нужно работать, то можно shallow copy сделать: `git clone --depth 1`

Comment: @jfs тут понимаете в чем проблема, это не от меня зависит, и зачастую будут отправляться графические макеты в том или ином формате(может быть ещё что-то, я просто стараюсь думать наперед), а они бывают достаточно больших размеров, больше 100мб  точно, в общем я больше склоняюсь ко второму варианту, вопрос только насколько быстро выполняется кодирование файлов в base64 строку. И ещё такой вопрос, получившая сястрока может быть весьма длинной, не столкнусь ли я с проблемой при помещении такой, объемной, строки в запрос, со стороны того же сервера gitlab api.

Comment: @jfs предложение по shallow copy конечно хорошое, но не сильно поможет если сами файлы в репозитории весят прилично.

Comment: Если вы хотите именно api воспользоваться и у вас не получается [по документации](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#upload-a-file) загрузить файл, то создайте конкретный вопрос о конкретной ошибке¶ Лучше конечно пересмотреть подход и не пытаться хранить в git`е гигабайтные блобы. Чем git lfs не подходит?

Comment: Ситуация не очень понятна, если честно. А точнее неясно как используется git. У пользователей есть доступ к репозиторию на gitlab, но нужно чтобы они делали коммиты через Ваше приложение? Или у пользователей нет доступа к репозиторию и они работают только через приложение?

Comment: @defaultlocale у пользователя есть доступ к репозиторию, но коммитить и пушить файлы он будет через мою веб-морду

Comment: @Aiswe Тогда можете пояснить как будет работать второй способ? Если веб-морда не умеет авторизовываться от имени пользователя, то что ей не пересылай она не авторизуется.

Comment: @defaultlocale Она работает как приложение зарегистрированное на gitlab, авторизованный(на gitlab) пользователь получает на веб-морде ссылку на подтверждение доступа моего приложения к ресурсам пользователя, после подтверждение происходит редирект со стороны gitlab-а, где в параметры строки запроса передается код авторизации пользователя, после чего с помощью этого кода я отправляю запрос на получение данных пользователя в том числе и токена доступа (access_token) и вот уже с ним(токеном доступа) я могу обращаться к ресурсам пользователя через API, OAuth 2.0 короче.

Comment: @defaultlocale Почитать об OAuth 2.0 можете тут https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication или тут https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/oauth-2-ru

Comment: @Aiswe Замечательно! Стало яснее, спасибо! Тем не менее, есть непонятный момент: в первом варианте у Вас основная проблема —  авторизация (как я понял, не получается push с токеном, хотя, вроде бы, [должен получится](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/10677)). Непонятно, как использование python-gitlab поможет с этим, ведь механизм авторизации в обоих случаях одинаков.

Comment: @defaultlocale спасибо за инфу, механизм авторизации всё же разный, авторизация в api по login:password паре не поддерживается с какой-то 10 версии gitlab API, а на счет использования токена доступа как пароля, сам я почему-то нагуглить не смог, попробую и попозже отпишусь :)

Comment: @defaultlocale кроме того по указанный вами ссылке не ясно, это возможность указывать access_token as password in git client?(типо через терминал) или же как пароль при запросе к API ?

Comment: @defaultlocale нагуглил, в общем это действительно дает возможность пушить код через консольку с помощью access_token, чуть позже проверю отпишусь

Comment: @Aiswe: чем вам [ссылка на документацию](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#upload-a-file) не устроила? Чем вариант, который вы "нагуглили" отличается?

Comment: @jfs вы меня удивляете или же я чего-то не знаю, вы сами читали инфу по ссылке что вы мне кинули? Я лично это видел и до вашего комментария, я привык гуглить прежде чем задавать вопрос. Цитирую: "Uploads a file to the specified project to be used in an issue or merge request description, or a comment." Похоже на то что мне нужно ? Или вы знаете как файл загруженный этим образом можно после переместить непосредственно в репозиторий ? Я загрузил таким образом файл и после его даже нашел, но переместить в репозиторий и добавить его в commit у меня не вышло, если вы знаете способ может опишите?

Comment: @Aiswe моя ошибка. смотрел на саму curl команду, пропустил про "issue, merge requests". (это я неосознанно, неявно продвигал идею, что большим блобам не место в самом репозитории :) Сильно отличаются команды, особенно часть связанная с авторизацией? Почему свой ответ не добавили?

Comment: @jfs не понял ваших вопросов(мб потому что мало спал). Какие команды отличаются от каких команд? Какой свой ответ? На какой вопрос?:)

Comment: "Какой вопрос?" —Под каким вопросом вы комментируете? "Какой свой ответ?" —если вы думаете что нашли решение на текущий вопрос, то можете опубликовать свой ответ. Это явно приветствуется. https:/ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer "Каких команд?" —вы выше упомянули, про "пушить через консольку" (я это прочитал как "через командную строку" — то есть команда, которую можно выполнить). Другая команда это curl.. по дважды поиведённой ссылке из документации  с токеном. Вопрос был насколько сильно авторизации отличаются в варианте с "пушить через консольку" и упомянутой curl командой.

Comment: @jfs под пушить через консольку я подразумевал пушить непосредственно командой git push remove_repo branch. Я пока не решил задачу, занят другими вещами, как только приду к решению, обязательно сюда напишу, не первый день как родился :)

Answer (score 1):

На github принимаются токены вместо паролей при работе по https. Попробуйте с гитлабом https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/#using-a-token-on-the-command-line

Comment: Я почитал и нашёл что эта хитрость позволяет только клонировать репозиторий, а вот пушить на удаленный репозиторий уже нет, по крайней мере в оф. документации такого нет. Но в любом случае спасибо за интересную инфу :)

Comment: клонирует он без пароля и логина по хттп. А вот с правильным паролем можно и пушить.